# Apache Camel AWS S3: credential expiration and temporary credentials

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-camel

Apache Camel interfaces well with AWS S3, but I have found a scenario in which it is not built correctly for. Going over all of the Camel examples I have seen online, I have never seen anyone use the recommended, industry standard, AWS temporary credentials on non-local environments. Using static credentials that live for ~6 months is a security issue as well as a manual burden (to refresh) and realistically shouldn't be used anywhere except for local environments.

Given a custom, s3 client setup, Camel can take temporary credentials, however, a Camel route pointed to AWS S3 will experience an expiration at some point. Camel is not smart enough to know this and will continue to try to poll a S3 bucket without throwing any exceptions or timeout errors indefinitely.

I have tried to add a timeout configuration to my endpoint like so:

```
aws-s3://" + incomingAWSBucket + "?" + "amazonS3Client=#amazonS3Client&timeout=4000
```

Can anyone explain how to interface Camel with AWS temporary credentials or throw an exception if AWS credentials expire (given the aforementioned setup)?

Thanks for the help!

---

**UPDATE:**

I pushed a feature to Apache Camel to handle the issue above:
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-aws-s3/src/main/docs/aws-s3-component.adoc#use-useiamcredentials-with-the-s3-component

Comment: Can you tell more, which Camel version do you use, and do you use that endpoint in a route from or what? And what do you want to do in case of a expired credentials

Comment: Camel version 2.20.0, I have one route that is pointing to AWS s3 and the "to" route is my local directory. Lastly, I would like camel to throw an exception if the credentials no longer work (timeout exception basically).

Comment: I have yet to prove this, but it seems like using a custom S3 client that depends on the default credential chain of AWS within the camel process will result in a client that manages the credentials itself. I will update this when I finish my experiment: AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2).build();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is dense enough for a tutorial if others want it. For now, I will copy and paste it to the correct forums and threads to get the word out:

Without complaining too much, I'd just like to say that for how powerful Camel is, its documentation and example base is really lacking for production scenarios in the AWS world... *Sigh...* Thats a mouthful and probably a stretch for any open source lib.

I figured out how to solve the credential problem by referencing the official [camel-s3 documentation](https://camel.apache.org/aws-s3.html) to first see how to create an advanced S3 configuration (relying on the aws sdk itself -- you can see a bare bones example there -- it makes the s3 client manually).
After I figured this out, I went out to the [aws sdk documentation on IAM credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html) to figure out how this could work on an EC2 instance since I am able to build the client itself. In the aforementioned docs, there are a few bare bones examples as well. Upon testing testing with the examples listed, I found that the credential refresh (the sole purpose of this question) was not working. It could get credentials at first, but it was not refreshing them during my tests after they were manually expired. 
Lastly, I figured out that you can specify a provider chain that can handle the refreshing of the credentials on its own. The aws documentation that explains this is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-roles.html).

In the end, I still need to have static credentials for my local camel setups that poll aws s3 buckets, however, my remote environments that live on ec2s can access them with temporary credentials that refresh themselves flawlessly. WOWSA! :)

To do this, I simply made a factory that uses a local camel setup for my local development and remote camel setup that relies on the temporary IAM credentials. This saves me the security concern and the work on needing to manually refresh credentials for all remote environments!

I will not explain how to create a factory or how my local & remote configurations are set up entirely, but I will include my code sample of the AmazonS3ClientBuilder that creates an S3 Client for remote setups.

```
AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
   .withCredentials(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(false))
   .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2)
   .build();
```

If there is a desire on how I got this to work, I can provide an example project that shows the entire process.

By request, here are my local and remote implementations of the s3 client:
Local:

```
public class LocalAWSS3ClientManagerImpl implements AWSS3ClientManager {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LocalAWSS3ClientManagerImpl.class);
    private PriorityCodeSourcesRoutesProperties priorityCodeSourcesRoutesProperties;
    private SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
    private CamelContext camelContext;

public LocalAWSS3ClientManagerImpl(PriorityCodeSourcesRoutesProperties priorityCodeSourcesRoutesProperties) {
    this.priorityCodeSourcesRoutesProperties = priorityCodeSourcesRoutesProperties;
    registry.put("amazonS3Client", getS3Client());
    camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);
    logger.info("Creating an AWS S3 manager for a local instance (you should not see this on AWS EC2s).");
}

private AmazonS3 getS3Client() {
    try {
        String awsBucketAccessKey = priorityCodeSourcesRoutesProperties.getAwsBucketAccessKey();
        String awsBucketSecretKey = priorityCodeSourcesRoutesProperties.getAwsBucketSecretKey();
        AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsBucketAccessKey, awsBucketSecretKey);
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(
                new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials)).build();
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        logger.error("Could not create AWS S3 client with the given credentials from the local config.");
    }
    return null;
}

public Endpoint getIncomingAWSEndpoint(final String incomingAWSBucket, final String region,
        final String fileNameToSaveAndDownload) {
    return camelContext.getEndpoint(
            "aws-s3://" + incomingAWSBucket + "?" + "amazonS3Client=#amazonS3Client"
            + "&region=" + region + "&deleteAfterRead=false" + "&prefix=" + fileNameToSaveAndDownload);
}

public Endpoint getOutgoingLocalEndpoint(final String outgoingEndpointDirectory,
        final String fileNameToSaveAndDownload) {
    return camelContext.getEndpoint(
            "file://" + outgoingEndpointDirectory + "?" + "fileName="
            + fileNameToSaveAndDownload + "&readLock=markerFile");
}
}
```

Remote:

```
public class RemoteAWSS3ClientManagerImpl implements AWSS3ClientManager {
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RemoteAWSS3ClientManagerImpl.class);
private PriorityCodeSourcesRoutesProperties priorityCodeSourcesRoutesProperties;
private SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
private CamelContext camelContext;

public RemoteAWSS3ClientManagerImpl(PriorityCodeSourcesRoutesProperties priorityCodeSourcesRoutesProperties) {
    this.priorityCodeSourcesRoutesProperties = priorityCodeSourcesRoutesProperties;
    registry.put("amazonS3Client", getS3Client());
    camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);
    logger.info("Creating an AWS S3 client for a remote instance (normal for ec2s).");
}

private AmazonS3 getS3Client() {
    try {
        logger.info("Attempting to create an AWS S3 client with IAM role's temporary credentials.");
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                                    .withCredentials(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(false))
                                    .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2)
                                    .build();
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        logger.error("Could not create AWS S3 client with the given credentials from the instance. "
                     + "The default credential chain was used to create the AWS S3 client. "
                     + ex.toString());
    }
    return null;
}

public Endpoint getIncomingAWSEndpoint(final String incomingAWSBucket, final String region,
        final String fileNameToSaveAndDownload) {
    return camelContext.getEndpoint(
            "aws-s3://" + incomingAWSBucket + "?" + "amazonS3Client=#amazonS3Client"
            + "&region=" + region + "&deleteAfterRead=false" + "&prefix=" + fileNameToSaveAndDownload);
}

public Endpoint getOutgoingLocalEndpoint(final String outgoingEndpointDirectory,
        final String fileNameToSaveAndDownload) {
    return camelContext.getEndpoint(
            "file://" + outgoingEndpointDirectory + "?" + "fileName="
            + fileNameToSaveAndDownload + "&readLock=markerFile");
}

}
```

Comment: This is really interesting. In Camel 2.21.x we are changing the client configuration a bit https://github.com/apache/camel/commit/60d0ed8b43c0860ab42abb436df05f5c7a5a9e25 Can you point me to an example project?

Comment: I could make one, but I'd rather not unless its absolutely necessary. 

When I get time this week, I will add the complete classes to give more of an idea on how I assemble the remote and local clients.

Comment: In regards to the commit that you sent, I do not see how this significantly extends the functionality. It still relies on static credentials (which is probably a good default behavior), however, the code could be modified to handle both scenarios (remote and local) properly if that was desired.

Comment: Also, I am fairly interested in contributing to Camel, but I am unaware of how one can get started.

Comment: You can get some information here: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Comment: For what its worth, I committed this to the apache camel repo. You can use the features described here from the docs: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-aws-s3/src/main/docs/aws-s3-component.adoc#use-useiamcredentials-with-the-s3-component